# Neo4j multitenancy

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

In my application I'd like to implement multi tenancy support for different customers.

I have a trees of nodes and would like to implement support of private trees for different customers.

Is there native Neo4j support for multi tenancy or it should be implemented as a custom business logic(for example I need to add a tenant Id to an each query) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Disclaimer: I'm the CEO of GrapheneDB, cloud hosting service for Neo4j]

Neo4j does not natively support multi-tenancy. AFAIK you basically have following options:

- **App-level** multi-tenancy: You store multiple subgraphs in one single database and your app takes care of isolation and access control.
- **Containerized/virtualized** multi-tenancy: It's a what we do at [GrapheneDB](http://www.graphenedb.com) in order to offer an affordable starting level tier.
- Using **individual servers**, one per database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll review GrapheneDB service.

Comment: If I would go with App-level multi-tenancy. Would you recommand that each node has a userid property, or that each node has a relation to a :USER node ?